# Are destructor methods used implicitly by the garbage collector, and dispose methods used by developers to explicitly dispose of objects?

Tags: c#, destructor, dispose, idisposable, finalizer

I can see there's already a lot of threads regarding dispose vs. destructor methods but I just want to make sure that I'm understanding them correctly before I move on.

Are destructor methods used implicitly by the garbage collector for when objects are no longer referenced (i.e. no longer needed) and dispose methods used by us developers to explicitly dispose of objects that may not be handled by the garbage collector?

Also - I'm reading into all this now and it seems that it's a case of one or the other with these methods. So for example given the following code:

```
class DansClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing...");
    }

    -DansClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Destructing...");
    }
}
```

The output will be:

**Destructing...**

Understandable, as we've suppressed the finalize (destructor) so we only see the Dispose output.

But if I comment out the SuppressFinalize() method the output is:

**Disposing...**

Why isn't the destructor called as well?

Comment: @Daniel If you've seen 'a lot of threads' on the two, *why* are you retreading the same ground?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Because from the other threads I'm trying to build up my own understanding - and I haven't seen any of the other threads address the issue I raised in the 2nd half of my question. If it stresses you out that much then leave the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispose methods, finalizers, and C#'s ironically-named destructors, exist because many objects ask other entities to do things on their behalf until further notice (typically granting exclusive use of something like a file, a region of memory, communications stream, hardware device, GDI handle, etc.); if an object issuing such a request were to disappear without those other entities know their services are no longer required, anything that had been set aside on behalf of the abandoned object would remain uselessly inaccessible.

The `IDisposable.Dispose` method provides a nice consistent way of telling an object that it will no longer be asked to do anything would require the assistance of other entities, and that any other entities which were doing anything on its behalf should be told to stop doing so.  If `IDisposable.Dispose` is called properly, objects can minimize the extent to which outside entities have to act on their behalf.

Unfortunately, for various reasons (most being easily avoidable; some not), objects are sometimes abandoned without `IDisposable.Dispose` having been called.  This will result in outside entities having to uselessly keep acting, at least for awhile, on behalf of the objects which are abandoned.  To avoid having outside entities act forever on behalf of outside entities, the system can notify objects that they have been abandoned, thus giving them a chance to inform outside entities of this fact.  Whenever an object whose class overrides `Object.Finalize` is created, it will be placed in a special list of objects that want to be notified if they are abandoned.  Existence on this list, by itself, is not enough to make an object be considered "live", but before the garbage collector removes dead objects from memory it will check whether they are on the notify-before-destruction list.  All dead objects which are on the list will be moved from the list of objects requesting notification if/when they are abandoned to a list of objects needing to be notified that they *have* been abandoned.  Placement on this second list will cause the dead objects, *and any objects to which they hold references*, to be considered "alive" again, at least until the notification has been performed.  When they are moved to the second list, however, they are removed from the first list so that if they are later found to be dead again, they will be swept from memory without further notice.

After the garbage collection completes, if any objects are in the list of objects needing to be notified of abandonment, the system will call the `Object.Finalize` method of each such object.  Typically, once `Object.Finalize` has been called on such an object, there won't be any more rooted references to it and it will vanish on the next garbage collection.  It is possible, however, for objects to be resurrected.

In vb.net and, so far as I know, most .net languages, one overrides `Object.Finalize` by simply declaring an override in the usual fashion.  For whatever reason, the creators of C# decided to forbid that.  Instead, in C#, one must use a language structure, ironically called a "Destructor", to override `Finalize` so that objects which are found to be abandoned will *not* be destroyed without notice, but instead be given a chance to clean up.

There are many tricky wrinkles in the actual operation of `Object.Finalize`, and it is best to avoid relying upon it except when absolutely necessary.  The ironically-named "destructors" don't actually destroy objects, but rather delay their destruction.  Calling `GC.SuppressFinalize()` on an object will remove it from the list of objects requesting notification when they are abandoned; provided that `Dispose` is called on an object, and it in turn calls `GC.SuppressFinalize()` as its *last* operation, there isn't any particular harm in having an object override `Finalize` or declare a "destructor", but in general it's best to only override `Finalize` (or declare "destructors") in relatively simple classes.

Answer (score 6):

Well the behavior you're seeing is because [Finalizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) (what you're refering to as a Destructor is also known as a Finalizer in .Net) are queued up to run in the background by the Garbage Collector.

*Eventually* it will be called (although in some instances it may not). [You can force their execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers.aspx), however, to understand what is going on:

```
// Assuming you remove the GC.SuppressFinalize call
myDisposable.Dispose();

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
// Output:
// Disposing...
// Destructing...
```

You only need to implement the pattern when you have external resources, or encapsulate members which contain external resources. Finalizers should only be implemented when you have external, unmanaged resources.

Proper implementation of the `IDisposable` pattern requires:

- **`Dispose`** cleans up *both unmanaged and managed* resources
- **Finalizer** cleans up hanging, *unmanaged* resources (if none exist, it is not needed)
- Neither may throw an exception, `Dispose` must be callable more than once
- The Finalizer should call the `Dispose` implementation
- Domain specific *termination* methods, like `Close`, should be functionally equivalent to `Dispose` if both exist

Comment: "What you're refering to as a Destructor is known as a Finalizer in .Net" - and a Finalizer is known as a destructor in C#...

Comment: I've added the missing "also". I try to avoid *destructor* to avoid the confusion with C++ semantics.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: A C# "destructor" is an ironically-named (and IMHO silly) language construct which instructs the compiler to override `Object.Finalize` with a method which will include the supplied code but also do a few other things, most notably calling `base.Finalize()`.  While C# "destructors" cause `Finalize` to be overridden, they are not quite the same thing as Finalizers.

Comment: @superca - They are the closest thing to a Finalizer for a C# programmer, since Finalize does not exists. C# does not have (other) Finalizers. And `~ClassName(){}` is officially a destructor, like it or not.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I am aware that C# unfortunately forbids programmers from overriding `Object.Finalize`, and thus the ironically-named "destructor" construct is the only way to access them.  I do think it's important to note, however, that "C# destructor" and "Finalizer" are not quite synonymous.  Among other things, a call to `base.Finalize()` is performed following the execution of the programmer-supplied code in a destructor, but is not performed following the execution of a finalizer.

Comment: @supercat - So C# won't allow  you to write a broken Finalizer, big deal... See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx#Y73

Comment: @HenkHolterman: C# allows plenty of ways of writing broken finalization code.  With regard to calling `base.Finalize()`, the requirement to call it does not imply that it should not be wrapped by other code nor a `try` block.  The Microsoft Dispose pattern renders the issue largely moot, since Finalize() shouldn't contain any logic and there's no need for a derived class to override it if a parent class does so.